# Extract digits within different scopes in String using regex

Tags: regex

I want to extract all digits within different scopes.

**1st scope:** `$ $`
**2nd scope:** `# #`

Extract all digits within the **1st scope**

`$1-2$`

Wished result

```
1, 2
```

`$1#4#-2$`

Wished result

```
1, 2
```

Extract all digits within the **2nd scope**

`$1-2#4-9-6#3-4$`

Wished result

```
4, 9, 6
```

**Note** The `-` is there to separate each digit and the number of digits in each scope may differ from time to time

My current Regex: `(^[$])([\d]+)(|-\d+)*(|#[\d]+((|-\d+)*)#)([$]+)($)`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your regex flavor and what is your current regex?

Comment: I want this to be done in Java so `Perl-like`. I have written a regex just to verify what the string must look like. Haven't managed to get any further @anubhava

Comment: added my regex @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For scope-1 matches you can use this regex:**

```bash
(?:\$|(?!^)\G(?:#[^#]*#)?-)\K\d+(?=[-\d#]*\$)

# without \K for Java
(?:\$|(?!^)\G(?:#[^#]*#)?-)(\d+)(?=[-\d#]*\$)
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/aKnkDi/1)

**For scope-2 matches you can use this regex:**

```bash
(?:#|(?!^)\G(?:\$[^$]*\$)?-)\K\d+(?=[\d$-]*#)

# without \K for Java
(?:#|(?!^)\G(?:\$[^$]*\$)?-)(\d+)(?=[-\d$]*#)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/7Wipnz/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. Thus `(?!^)\G` matches position at the end of previous match
- `\K`: Reset matched info
- `(?=[\d$-]*#` is lookahead to assert that we have presence of `#` after matching 0 or more digits/`$`/`-`
- `(?=[\d#-]*\$` is lookahead to assert that we have presence of `$` after matching 0 or more digits/`#`/`-`

Comment: `\K` This boundary is not supported in this regex dialect

Comment: If `\K` is not there then you need to use capture group: `(?:\$|(?!^)\G(?:#[^#]*#)?-)(\d+)(?=[\d#-]*\$)`

Comment: @Herker: `(?:#|(?!^)\G(?:\$[^$]*\$)?-)(\d+)(?=[-\d$]*#)` will work fine in Java.

Comment: I have updated answer with both Perl and Java compliant regex. It is always better to add regex flavor in question itself so that you get best possible answer.